# MVC Handling nested action methods?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, design-patterns, url-routing

I've got a Project class which contains one or more issues:

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public List<Issue> Issues {get; set;}
}

public class Issue
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
}
```

I'm having trouble structuring my mvc app so that the Issues are a sub item of projects on the URL routes?

```
/projects/details/1/issues/ - Display list of project issues
/projects/details/1/issues/1 - Display issue #1
/projects/details/1/issues/2 - Display issue #2
/projects/details/1/issues/create/ - Create a new issue for project #1
```

My initial thoughts is to create a route which leads to the following Action Method

```
public ActionResult Details(int projectId, string action)
{
    if(action =="issues")
    {
      //Call ActionMethod...
    }
}
```

But it just doesn't feel right.  Any suggestions?  Is it true that something like this possible with RoR?

Answer (score 5):

You can provide a route for that action like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("ProjectIssues",
                "projects/{projectID}/issues/{issueID}",
                new { controller=Projects, action=Details});
```

Then requests like http://domain.com/projects/3/issues/5 would be mapped to your Details action in ProjectsController.

You can get the parameters with the same parameter names in route

```
public ActionResult Details(int projectID,int? issueID)
{
    if(issue.HasValue)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("IssueDetails",new {ProjectID=projectID,IssueID=issueID});
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("AllIssues",new {ProjectID=projectID});
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are missing the point of MVC. Its about separation of concerns not nesting down related domains.

You idea is nice but you need to implement `Strategy design pattern` to have clean code.

Although `Issue` and `Project` is directly related to each other but these are on different domain. So, better you separate these into different controller. You will be linking your **issues** when you will be dealing with your `Project` controller and vise versa for `Issue` controller

My suggestion would be for

- Display project issues - `/Issue/Details/1 //here 1 is the project number`
- Display single issue - `/Issue/View/1/101 //1 is the project number and 101 is issue number`
- Create issue - `/Issue/Create/1 //1 is the project number`

It's just my thoughts. Please feel free to argue on my methodology.